# SMD PTC Fuse for 24 VDC

Tags: fuses, polyfuse

I am designing a new version of a PCB board with a microcontroller to drive two 24 V DC brushed motors, and I am looking for a self-resetting PTC SMD fuse for a 24 VDC supply line and max 2.5 A. The current spikes present upon activation of the motors can be up to 3 A for a maximum duration of 80 ms (this current refers to that read on the power supply when a motion command is sent to the motors). I am currently using component [0154003.DR](https://mou.sr/43iZNvz) but would like to replace it with a self-resetting fuse. I have identified component [2920L150DR](https://mou.sr/3O5OHp7) (Vmax 33 V, Ih 1.5 A, It 3 A) but would like to be sure it will fit.

In general for the fuses I know that:

- the hold current (Ih) is the maximum current you can pass through, and guarantee the device will not trip over the specified temperature range;
- the trip current (It) is the value where a maximum time-to-trip is characterised. Any current over this value is guaranteed to trip the fuse, within the specified temperature range.

Any current in between may or may not trip the device depending on environmental temperature, current, component variation and how long its had the current passing through.

The current drawn by the motors is then limited internally through the firmware on the microcontroller that stabilizes it below 1 A, so I think component 2920L150DR may be okay.

Comment: What’s a PPTC fuse and how does it differ from a regular PTC one?

Comment: @winny PPTC stay for Polymeric Positive Temperature Coefficient. By comparison, the PPTC are positive polymer coefficient devices, a passive component used in the protection against current peaks in electronic circuits. They are similar in function to PTC thermistors, but operate with mechanical changes instead of charging the effects of the carrier on the semiconductors.

Comment: Check the reaction time and derating curves given in the datasheet. For 5 Amps it takes 2 seconds to open the circuit. Is it a short enough time for you? For 50°C ambient the hold current drops to 1.1A and the trip current drops to 2.25A. Is this still high enough for your operation and protection needs?

Comment: @RohatKılıç thank you for your response. I note indeed that rightly as the temperature changes the values of the currents change, in light of this I might consider a fuse with slightly higher specifications so as to have the desired behavior even for higher temperatures, although knowing the place where the component will be located one should not reach temperatures above 50 degrees.